# bison grammar error when adding a rule

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

Hi I m trying to make a very simple grammar and failing miserably when I try to combine 2 rules:

The flex file:

```
%option never-interactive
%option yylineno


D   [0-9]
L   [a-zA-Z_]
A   [a-zA-Z_0-9]
WS  [ \t\v\n\f]

%%
"keyword"       { printf("KEYWORD: %s\n", yytext); return KEYWORD; }
[+-]?{D}+       { yylval = atoi(yytext); return L_SINT32; }
{L}{A}*     { printf("ID: %s\n", yytext); return IDENTIFIER;    }
";"         { return EOS;       }
{WS}        { }
.           { printf("OTHER\n"); return 0; }

%%
```

and the corresponding bison file:

```
%token L_SINT32
%token EOS
%token IDENTIFIER KEYWORD
%start stmt_list

%%


idlist  : IDENTIFIER        { printf("IDENT\n"); }
    | idlist IDENTIFIER { printf("IDENT, IDENT\n"); }
    ;

stmt    : KEYWORD IDENTIFIER ';'
    | idlist ';'    { printf("EXP\n"); }
    ;

stmt_list
    : stmt
    | stmt_list stmt
;

%%
```

When I try to use that on the input

```
id0 id1 id2;
keyword id1;
```

I get:

```
ID: id0
IDENT
ID: id1
IDENT, IDENT
ID: id2
IDENT, IDENT
error -> syntax error
```

Can someone points me out why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your lexer sees a semicolon:

```
";"         { return EOS;       }
```

What your parser is looking for:

```
| idlist ';'    { printf("EXP\n"); }
```

`EOS` will have some value created by bison and put in the generated header file; it might be 258. `';'`, on the other hand, has the value `';'` (i.e. `0x3B` or `59`).

I'd get rid of EOS and just `return ';'` from the lexer.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day, the problem was indeed in the returned lexem!